# file comparison with memory consideration

Tags: java, file, memory-management, arrays, file-comparison

I want to compare two files, one is in file system and the other is being downloaded from a HTTP URL.

We have tried to compare by byte[] arrays (we used HTTPRequestBuilder by Apache), but the concern is that the files may be too large and they may exhaust the memory. Do we have any good alternates.

Comment: Do you want to compare the files merely to see if they're equal or get the actual differences between them?

Answer (score 2):

You can compare the contents from two `InputStream` objects by reading just a buffer at a time. You'll need to read data as and when you "run out" from each stream, noting that you when you call `read` you may not end up actually reading a full buffer.

The two streams are equal if each byte-by-byte comparison from the buffers is equal and the streams run out of data at the same time. I suspect the code may be slightly fiddly, but it shouldn't be too bad.

In fact, for simpler code, if you wrap each `InputStream` in a `BufferedInputStream`, you could probably *just* compare byte-by-byte (calling the parameterless `read()` method on each iteration) without losing too much performance:

```
public boolean equals(InputStream x, InputStream y)
{
    // TODO: Only wrap them if they're not already buffered
    x = new BufferedInputStream(x);
    y = new BufferedInputStream(y);

    while (true)
    {
        int xValue = x.read();
        int yValue = y.read();
        if (xValue != yValue)
        {
            return false;
        }
        if (xValue == -1)
        {
            // Reached the end of both streams at the same time
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Jon, but if suppose "InputStream x" is coming from http call, do we have any risk of losing connection or anything..?..

Comment: @Ahmad: There's always the risk that the connection will drop, sure... and you'll get an exception. I can't see how you could avoid that.

Comment: @Jon...that was my concern Jon..I think if we take the whole fle in byte array the risk will be lowest n that's what I am doing..